# Multiply operator overloading on vector class in c#

Tags: c#, class, operator-overloading

I guess, it's a pretty basic problem, but I couldn't find an answer.

Program is made for learning purpose, I'd defined a vector class with multiplication operator  like this:

```
public class vector
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public vector(int x,int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public static vector operator *(vector w1, vector w2)
    {
        return int w1.x*w2.x + w1.y * w2.y;
    }
}
```

The problem is that visual studio underlines the expression in return, how should I modify the definition of "*" operator to make it work ?

Comment: @ThomasD. You can *absolutely* overload the binary `*` operator in C#  (Note that you don't override operators, you overload them.)  You can't overload the *unary* `*` operator, but that's not what's being overloaded here.

Comment: @Servy you are absolutely right. Nice, I learned something today. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I think, the real problem is that multiplication transforms vector class object into integer number, it's possible to overload the "*" operator, I just can't find a way to return an int there and that's what I need help with.

Comment: @RafalKonklewski why would you want to return an `int` if you multiply 2 vectors? That makes no sense and I think you should not do that. The `*-operator` (and other basic operators) should never change the datatype imho.

Comment: @ThomasD. There is no unique definition for multiplying two vectors.  There are two sensible definitions, the dot product, and the cross product.  The dot product is a scalar, the cross product a vector.  Having "multiplication" of two vectors being a different type (a scalar value) is in fact sensible.  The problem is that you can't implement both using the `*` operator.

Comment: I want to make the "*" operator return the value of scalar multiplication(the dot product), which should be an int (if vector coordinates are also int).

Comment: The confusion between precisely what you mean by multiplying two vectors is why you probably shouldn't be relying on operator overloading to achieve it. Instead, you should handle this functionality in `DotMultiply` and `CrossMultiply` methods for clarity.

Comment: Well that would be easy, but can't I really just overload the operator ? In python for example it's easily doable like this: https://codeshare.io/2WdB0M however c# doesn't have the dynamic typing.

Answer (score 1):

You defined your function to return a `vector`, however you are only returning an `int`.

```
public static vector operator *(vector w1, vector w2)
{
    return int w1.x*w2.x + w1.y * w2.y;
}
```

should be

```
public static int operator *(vector w1, vector w2)
{
    return int (w1.x*w2.x + w1.y * w2.y);
}
```

Or for example, if you wanted to return a vector for the addition operator, that would look like:

```
public static vector operator +(vector w1, vector w2)
{
    return new vector (w1.x+w2.x, w1.y + w2.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a new instance of *vector*, try this:

```
public class vector
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public vector(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static vector operator *(vector w1, vector w2)
    {
        return new vector(w1.x* w2.x, w1.y * w2.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the problem, you don't get a vector if you want to get the scalar multiplication of 2 vectors, just an int value (real in general), there'll be the same problem if I'd like to get the abs of complex number. It's easily doable in python, like this: def __mul__(self,second):
            return self.x*second.x+self.y*second.y

Comment: @RafalKonklewski I see. Check Xander's answer on obtaining an integer.